# How to Install VMWare ESXi in System76?

Tags: installation, vmware

Currently have `System76` Hardware that was used to run an trial `Openstack` environment.

I'm looking at attempting to load `VMWare ESXi 5.5.0 update 3` onto the hardware but it keeps `rebooting/power cycling` the hardware.

Anyone else used `System76` Hardware and tried installing `VMWare ESXi` onto it?

Answer (score 0):

I think System76  is not on the HCL from VMware.

R\Sven